# How to set encoding in fluent NHibernate?

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, character-encoding

I have created my database by this sql query:
  `("CREATE DATABASE " + DBName + " DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci", connection)`

And I have this fluent configuration:

```
Fluently.Configure()
                     .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(c => c.Server(server)
                        .Database(DBName).Username(username).Password(password)))
                     .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
                     .BuildSessionFactory();
```

How can I set NHibernate encoding in this configuration? or how can I set my mappings encoding?

I want to this because when I want to select with a property which has UTF8 encoding NHibernate sql will include ??????? in strings with encoding

Comment: Are you specifying the UTF8 charset in your MySQL connection string?

Comment: now I tried this connection string and now it's okay. But I forced to use a string in my configuration. Isn't there a way to use charset in connection string with linq? like my code I have written?

Comment: I'm not sure if fluent has anything to expose charset when you go through that path, but if you store the connection string as one item in your config file there is c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("connectionStringName").  If you don't want to use a string in your config file you can use c.Is("string") and build the connection string the way you've got it above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var mysqlconf = MySQLConfiguration.Standard
.ConnectionString(c => c.Is("Server=srv;Database=db;User=dev;Password=pass;CharSet=utf8"));

return Fluently.Configure().Database(mysqlconf).Mappings(m =>
    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>()).BuildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting the database encoding is not related to Fluent NHibernate. Check your connection string, it should be like:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=user;Pwd=passw; CharSet=UTF8;
```

Comment: please read my upper comment. Isn't there a way to define charset using linq?

Comment: FYI, you should write it as: CharSet=utf8; and not CAPS.